# WPF own UserControl with ItemsSource Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, itemssource

I want to create a own Usercontrol with an ItemsSource Property. 
I have created a UserControl "myContainer" and i have created a UserControl "myItem". Now I want to show the myItem Controls in the myContainer Control. So I declared a dependency Property ItemsSource in the myContainer Control.
But if i start a testproject and bind a collection to the itemssource property nothing happend. is that the right way to implement a itemssource property?

**Xaml: myContainer**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Control.myContainer"
         ...
         x:Name="myUserControl">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel x:Name="myDockPanel">

    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind myContainer**

```
public partial class myContainer : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(myItem), typeof(myContainer));

    public myContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<myItem> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<myItem>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemsSource");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml myItem**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Control.myItem"
         ... 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="2">
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="LightGray">
                <DockPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                    <Button x:Name="Button_Close" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="14" Height="14" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Button_Undock" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="14" Height="14" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Header,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" ContentSource="Content"></ContentPresenter>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**CodeBehind myItem**

```
 public partial class myItem : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static DependencyProperty _Header =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(String), typeof(myItem), new UIPropertyMetadata("Item"));

    public myItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public String Header
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)GetValue(_Header);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(_Header, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Header");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be far easier to derive from ListBox or ItemsControl and set the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property to a DockPanel. By overriding [GetContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride.aspx) you could create your own item type.

Comment: @Clemens i think this is the answer to the question instead of a comment

Comment: can you show me an example for that?

Comment: From your code it's hard to tell what exactly you're going to achieve. I guess your item shall display a header text and some other content (whatever that is). Can you provide a bit more information about what you want to? What is your item type and how shall it be visualized?

Comment: And you should know this artice: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: myitem has two parts. a header(name of the content) and a content part where i want to load a usercontrol. in the container i want to load one, two, three or more myitems that are displayed among.

Comment: Why a UserControl and not a ListBoxItem with a DataTemplate? The latter would be the typical way to do it in WPF. And please, if you respone here, add *@Clemens* to you comment. I'll be notified then.

Comment: @Clemens: i thought i would be more flexible with the usercontrol. because for the next steps i wanted to add drag drop functionallity to change the items order. do you know an example to do something like that with a ListBoxItem? (the drag/drop is now not so important. first i want to have the items in my container) :)

Comment: Did you read the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article?

Comment: @Clemens now i read the article and i think i understand it that the way with the data template is not so bad. i want to use these in many places, so i could create the data template as a ressource.i would prefer to add it in a custom user control with an itemsource and then the data template in it. but so i also have the problem with the dependency property

Comment: "i also have the problem with the dependency property". Then you haven't read the answer to your other question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have an item type that basically looks like this:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public object Content { get; set; }
}
```

You may display items of this type by means of a ListBox with a `DataTemplate` for the items, set by the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Aqua">
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You may of course use your specialized UserControl inside the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Aqua">
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            <local:MyItemControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

The default panel used by a ListBox is a VirtualizingStackPanel. If you want to use a DockPanel instead, you can achive that by setting the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

---

EDIT: Instead of using a DataTemplate you may also completely replace the visual appearance of a ListBoxItem by replacing its ControlTemplate in a Style in `ItemsContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Aqua">
                            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: is there a way to show an usercontrol in listbox item? i do this but when i click a button in the user control for example only the listboxitem is selected

Comment: You may set [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) instead of ItemTemplate.

Comment: I only find a way to style the ListBoxItem, but i can't use the objects in the usercontrol :/

Comment: What I mean is setting the ListBoxItem's ControlTemplate in a Style setter. See my edit.

Comment: I exactly do it like in your example and the listboxitems are shown correctly but i cannot access the objects(button) in the usercontrol that is loaded in the contentpresenter by the binding. I see the button but can't click it

Comment: I can't guess what's going wrong there. Maybe you need to replace the ContentPresenter by your UserControl. But that is out of scope of this question.